# Allowing a query string through .htaccess password protection

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, paypal-ipn, .htpasswd

I have a staging site where I have secured it using .htaccess password.

However, as it's an eCommerce site, I need paypal's IPN to be able the communicate with my site.

I'm using the following .htaccess but it's not working. The password protect is still in effect.

```
Deny from all
Order deny,allow
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Area"
AuthUserFile "/path/to/htpasswd"
require valid-user

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^paypalListener=paypal_standard_IPN$
  RewriteRule .* - [E=test_uri]
</IfModule>

#Allow valid-user
Allow from env=test_uri
Satisfy any
```

Can anyone guide me on what is wrong here?

Comment: What happens actually? You get a 500 Server Error, or it just asks for password even for paypal URLs ?

Comment: The password protect is still in effect, so i'm wondering if my rules are wrongly written?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, from what I can see, `[E=test_uri]` just sets "test_uri" to an empty string, so doesn't do anything. Also, `Allow from` expects an IP or domain (ex. PayPal's servers making the request to your site).

So it might work if you properly set the environment variable to the remote address making the request, like this:

```
RewriteRule .* - [E=test_uri:%{REMOTE_ADDR}]
```

I can't test this right now though.

Also make sure that there aren't other authentication rules in the server's .conf file and that authentication directives in .htaccess files are parsed (`Options AuthConfig`).

Comment: Hey thanks, but the same problem still persists. My method actually comes from here http://css-tricks.com/snippets/htaccess/allow-single-url/ but because i wanted to allow a query string i ended up using mod rewrite

Comment: I tested this and on localhost, the `test_uri` gets set to 127.0.0.1. When I use `Allow from 127.0.0.1`, password protection is off. But when combining all this and use `Allow from env=test_uri`, which is a valid statement afterall, doesn't work, and `test_uri` gets unset. Even when you login with a valid user/password, `test_uri` gets unset. I'm puzzled.

Comment: Now that's really mind boggling. I've tried uri and ip as well they all work fine.